# Access 2007 - saving calculation in access table

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, field

I have used access in the past, but on a very limited basis.

I am trying to take a calculated field on my form and have it save to the database.

My fields are:  quantity, cost, subtotal

In my form I changed the Control Source of the subtotal field to this:
=[quantity]*[cost]

The form does show the correct calculation total.

Then under event I created an afterupdate event:

Private Sub subtotal_AfterUpdate()
Me.subtotal = [quanity] * [cost]
End Sub

Does not save to the database.

I have tried many different ideas from the internet and they all failed.  So I am missing something.  I do need the subtotal to save to the database as I will use it later in other forms and reports.

***Actually I probably should clarify I want the RESULT of the calculation to save in the subtotal field, not the calculation itself.***

Thank you so much,

Kim

Comment: In general, it's not recommended to save a calculated field in Database. Instead, just modify your SELECT query to include the calculation, like SELECT [quantity], [cost], [quantity]*[cost] As SubTotal FROM... (the rest of query)

Comment: I understand that but I would like it saved for various reasons, I don't want it to have to calculate each time, just the one time and it be put into the database.

Answer (score 0):

YES! I got it to work :)

I created a BeforeUpdate event for the quantity field: (since it is part of the calculation)

Private Sub quantity_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Me.subtotal = Me.quantity * Me.cost
End Sub

It works great, even updates when quantity or cost changes in the form, and it stores the result as I need.

Kim